# Difference between stem and normalized_stem in wowool lexicons

Tags: dictionary, nlp

I am using wowool but in the lexicons I don't see any difference between stem or normalized_stem. When should I use one or the other?
My sample is from the documentation: "I like kiwis. KIWIS are good."
Both seem to match with

`lexicon: (input="stem") : { kiwi } =Fruit;`

and

`lexicon: (input="normalized_stem") : { kiwi } =Fruit;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal because the root form of `KIWIS` is `kiwi`so the stem and normalized_stem will match.
If you would use Kiwi with a initial capital then only the normalized_stem will match, the reason is the stem of Kiwi is a Proper Noun so it will not be stemmed.
I advise you to look at the stem of the words when you are trying to decide whether to use stem or normalized_stem.

```
    // Wowool Source
    lexicon: (input="stem") { kiwi } =S_Fruit;
    lexicon: (input="normalized_stem") { kiwi } =NS_Fruit;
```

```
./wow -l en -i "I like kiwis. I like Kiwis are good. Kiwis" --domains rules
```

```
    -- EyeOnText WoWoolConsole 2.1.0
    1:Process:stream_16840253095957608044 (42b/42b)
    Language:english
    s(0,13)
    {Sentence
        t(0,1) "I" (init-cap, init-token)['I':Pron-Pers, +1p, +sg]
        t(2,6) "like" ['like':V-Pres, +inf, +positive]
    {NS_Fruit
    {S_Fruit
        t(7,12) "kiwis" ['kiwi':Nn-Pl]
    }S_Fruit }NS_Fruit
        t(12,13) "." ['.':Punct-Sent]
    }Sentence
    s(14,36)
    {Sentence
        t(14,15) "I" (init-cap, init-token)['I':Pron-Pers, +1p, +sg]
        t(16,20) "like" ['like':V-Pres, +inf, +positive]
        t(21,26) "Kiwis" (init-cap, nf, nf-lex)['Kiwis':Prop-Std]
        t(27,30) "are" ['be':V-Pres-Pl-be]
        t(31,35) "good" ['good':Adj-Std]
        t(35,36) "." ['.':Punct-Sent]
    }Sentence
    s(37,42)
    {Sentence
    {NS_Fruit
    {S_Fruit
        t(37,42) "Kiwis" (init-cap, init-token)['kiwi':Nn-Pl]
    }S_Fruit }NS_Fruit }Sentence
```